# Android SQLite Listall data if column equals username [help writing a rawquery]

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I am trying to associate the unique data that user inputs directly back to them, I have a login that checks the username and password in SQLite and if it matches start activity intent then save details in SharedPref

From there for every new note a user makes it will take his username in sharedpref and add it to SQLite

How can query to getAll notes? So if SharedPref key value username equals creator column bring back all data that equals to keyvalue username == creator column.

```
    public void populateList(){
      Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();

      listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    control.close();
}

public class NotesAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public NotesAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    TextView body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_body);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_date);

    String getTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
    String getBody = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    String getDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));

    title.setText(getTitle);
    body.setText(getBody);
    date.setText(getDate);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the question?  Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public Cursor listNotes(String user) {
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE creator =  '" + user + "'", null);
}
```

Comment: I think I got it,  how can I pass this in a Listview?

Comment: you need to create a cursor adapter, check  [this article](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

Comment: Okay I have made an adapter, can you check my code, what do I call in populate List

Comment: you need to initialize your adapter and set the adapter to your listview -yourAdapter adap= new yourAdapter(this, yourCursor); -youtListView.setAdapter(adap);

Comment: yeah there's no problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017097/android-listview-wont-show-from-sqlite-return-cursor can you check this out and understand why my listview isnt updating

Comment: in the activity where is the listview, you can populate listview in the method onresume, or you can use broadcast receiver to fill data in the activy after insert or update the note.

Comment: if you check the link, I have upload all my code there, i odnt understand why my listview wont work

Comment: I'll just set my username to `bar"; DROP TABLE Notes; --`. Please use query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using raw queries is not recommended because it increases the chances of SQL injection. Instead use the following method:

```
//columns which you want to retrieve
String column[] = {dbHelper.ID,dbHelper.COURSE, dbHelper.ROOM,dbHelper.S_HOUR,dbHelper.S_MINUTE,dbHelper.E_HOUR, dbHelper.E_MINUTE};

         //Table Name               //Where clause arguemnts
db.query(dbHelper.TABLE_NAME,<column,dbHelper.DAY, arguement,null,null,null);
```

If you are using a list fragment then call the adapter in the following method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = getActivity();

        cursor = new DbAdapter(context).getData("Friday");
        cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(context,cursor);
        //you don't have to get the list view in list adapter it by default has one
        setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    }
```

replace following:

```
cursor = new DbAdapter(context).getData("Friday");
```

with

```
Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();
```