# Android - Fragment containg ListView, CursorAdapter using SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have a Fragment that contains a listView and button. When the button is clicked a DialogFragment will open where the user can input data into EditText fields. Once the user presses `setPositiveButton` it calls method in DBHelper to insert data into SQLite then dismisses dialogFragment

My problem, once it dismisses the ListView should update with the new input listing all future inputs. However I cant seem to get it to work. I have made a CursorAdapter. Does anyone know why it isnt working

```
public class NotesAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

DatabaseHelper help;
private Cursor c;
public NotesAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    c = cursor;
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    //View
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    TextView body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_body);
    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
    //Columns to bound into view
    String getTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
    String getBody = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    String getDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));

    title.setText(getTitle);
    body.setText(getBody);
    date.setText(getDate);
}
```

}

Query the database table notes, if sharedpref keyvalue username equals column_creator then return data, is my query right?

```
    public Cursor listNotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = help.getReadableDatabase();
    String username = session.getUser();
   // Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(listNotes))
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +help.NOTE_TABLE+ "WHERE " +help.CREATOR+ "= '" + username + "' COLLATE NOCASE", null);

 }

public class Notes extends Fragment {

NotesControl control;
NotesAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
Button add;
public static boolean isDataUpdated=false;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
    control = new NotesControl(getActivity());
    control.open();
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotesDialog dialog = new NotesDialog();
            dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Dialog Fragment");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    populateList();
}
```

Finally attaching the ListView to my Fragment, I made a method I can call to popluate the List

```
    public void populateList(){
      Cursor cursor = control.listNotes();
      listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      NotesAdapter adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    control.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss the dialog say by pressing OK then you have to notify the cursor that data has been changed you have to update yourself..

**Edit1:**
 Declare the cursor as data member of the class too :)
i want you to do something like the following
Implementation:

```
public class Notes extends Fragment {

NotesControl control;
NotesAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
Button add;
Cursor cursor;
public static boolean isDataUpdated=false;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotesDialog dialog = new NotesDialog();
            dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Dialog Fragment");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    control = new NotesControl(getActivity());
    control.open();
    populateList();
}

public void populateList(){
      cursor = control.listNotes();
      listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
      adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);

      listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    control.close();
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    if(isDataUpdated)
   {
     cursor.requery();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     Notes.isDataUpdated = false;
    }

}
```

**Important**
in your DialogFragment Ok button click event add the following snippet

```
Notes.isDataUpdated = true;
```

**PS:**
the method requery() is depricated. after getting the hang of this next logical step would be to user CursorLoaders

Comment: Where will I put that method and where shall i call it

Comment: define it as you have done with the populateList() method...and call it in the click method of the dialog box you have created to make the changes in the data base....for example on pressing OK..

Comment: one more thing you have to add the new data in the database first via insert query..

Comment: You have lost me, I have a dialogfragment where user inputs EditText then when he presses okay, it calls dbhelper insert and insert data into SQLite database. From there the dialogFragment will be dismissed and it should display the user input in listview but its not showing

Comment: kindly update your code in question..then it will be easy for me to help
you have done 90% of the work

Comment: the listview isnt appearing at all

Comment: my dear edit you code in the question and write the current code..i will try to sort it out then

Comment: thats my code, im trying to change things around too, but those are the code that is being used and still no update or display of the ListView

Comment: i have written the whole code for you, try that in your project

Comment: i have uploaded the logcat from the code             public void onClick(View v) {
                NotesDialog dialog = new NotesDialog();
                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Dialog Fragment");
            }